# ¿Como encuentro cual de mis columnas tiene un valor y retorno dicho valor mediante una consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me gustaria saber la forma de ver tres columnas y ver cual tiene un valor y dicho valor retornarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar en la imagen tengo tres columnas que dependiendo de lo que el usaurio ingrese mediante un excel debe escoger una de esas tres columnas, pero no se como hacer que la consulta cheque por registro cual columna tiene un valor y que lo regrese en la query, estoy trabajando sobre sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si dispones de SQL Server 2008 o superior cuentas con la función [`COALESCE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT COALESCE(Tarifa1, Tarifa2, Tarifa3)
       FROM TuTabla;
```

Básicamente, te devolverá el valor de la primera de las columnas (en orden) que no sea `NULL`